# How to deny POST to certain url in nginx

Tags: post, nginx, webserver

Some of the sql heavy urls on my app (say /members) are being attacked by botnets. So I'd like to disable anybody to post to these urls, while allowing others to GET them.

I tried to make a nested loop like this:

```
if ($request_uri ~ .*members^)  {

   if ($request_method ~ ^(POST)$ ) {
         return 444;
     }
}
```

But nginx does not accept this. So wondering how to apply the directive?

UPDATE:

I also tried

```
location ~ "^/members$" {
    if ($request_method ~ ^(POST)$ ) {       
        return 444;
    }
}
```

but this one deny GET too.

So still need help.

Answer (score 0):

I would block the bots like this (example bots):

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* LWP::Simple|BBBike|wget|Baiduspider|Jullo|msnbot|scrapbot) {

    return 403;
}
```

Comment: This is good when the user_agents are limited to the list above, but in my case, they agents are so diverse that there is no hope to be blocked this way.